# How to recover accidentally deleted Flutter code files?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, delete-directory

So I was cleaning my desktop and due to careless rm command I deleted my flutter project folder where my codebase was located I have the debug app of the version .I tried local history of the Android studio but was unsuccessful is there any way I can recover the code if not can I build a release app from the debug one

Comment: For some reason I can't edit the questions so please note:
The question title should be more in the manner of "How to recover deleted Flutter code files". In the question content, you should remove the story and stick to the question about how to recover the files or compile the debug to replease. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should use versioning to always have a save of your project.
Github, Gitlab, BitBucket, SVN are free, use it for the next time...

If you didn't obfuscate your Flutter app, you can probably extract the dart code of your app.

Comment: Yeah my bad although I use version control in all my other projects I was in hurry and regret it. No I haven't obfuscated the code how do you recommend I proceed to extract the code

Comment: I honestly don't know how to extract it, but its technically possible tho, maybe try to ask another question on StackOverflow ? or r/FlutterDev